# CSS: remove additional spaces between created by "float" command

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I've got a wordpress blog where I want to iterate through posts. Each post on the list has a little photos on the left. And title and subtitle on the right.

[image]
But as you can see distance between each post is not equal but rather related to the length of the title and subtitle. The longer text is the bigger distance between each posts. I want to change it to fixed length with the same size every time. How can I do it? Here is my code:

```
<div style="padding-top: 25px;" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <p>
        //IMAGE
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
            <a  style="float: left; padding-right: 25px;" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></a>   <?php endif; ?>
        //TITLE
    <h2 style="padding-top: -20px;"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'ari' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </h2>
       //SUBTITLE
    <?php echo get_secondary_title(); ?>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no negative padding

Comment: remove bottom padding and margin on your p and also h2 cannot be a child of p

Comment: negative padding doesn't exists!

Comment: Have you tried looking that up with your browser's debugging tools? This might help you to find the element that needs to be adjusted

Comment: `a` tag is not a block element. Add `display:inline-block` when apply `float` on it.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour inline elements can float too, after all, floats where created to position images (which are inline elements by default)

Comment: @Gobbin I use negative padding just to center text on the same line with the picture. Is that wrong?

Comment: than i would use `margin-top`. I can't make it clearer than this: padding's minimal value is 0. margin's minimal value is -infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the title and subititle max lenght truncating it.
Try this:

```
.text-to-truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Or check this out:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/hub/blogs/ellipse-my-text/